# Second fundamental form - Maple

Tags: tensor, maple

I would like to know the command/line in Maple 16 or similar to obtain the second fundamental form tensor for a given metric. I've managed to obtain Rienmann and Ricci tensor, even Weyl, but I can't find anything on the internet that would help me to obtain the K_mu_nu of a generic spherically symmetric metric such as:

```
gmetric := evalDG(A(r)*`&tensor`(dt, dt)+B(r)*`&tensor`(dr, dr)+r^2*`&tensor`(dtheta, dtheta)+r^2*sin(theta)^2*`&tensor`(dphi, dphi))
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance